# Passing pointer to function is'nt passing by reference in C?

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference

```
#include<stdio.h>
int func(int*);
int main(void)
{
        int a = 3;
        int *p = NULL;
        p = &a;
        printf("p = %p\n", p);
        func(p);
        printf("p inc: %p\n", p);
        return 0;
}
int func(int *p)
{
        p++;
        return 0;
}
```

Output: p=0x7fff6f87e89c
        p inc:0x7fff6f87e89c

Pointer p is passed to function func and pointer p is incremented in func, but in main function its address is still the same!! Passing pointer to function is'nt passing by reference?

Comment: NOTE: There is no **pass by reference in c**.

Comment: Do you want to incrementing `main`'s  `a`  or  `main`'s `p`?

Comment: I just want to check the address of pointer , I am incrementing the address of pointer in function func() ,want to check if its reflected in main()

Comment: Then you need to pass the address of the pointer, dereference it inside the function and increment the result of this dereferencing.

Answer (score 2):

Pointers are passed by value.
If you want to pass a pointer by reference, you just pass a pointer of a pointer!

Like so:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int func(int**);
int main(void)
{
    int a = 3;
    int *p = NULL;
    p = &a;
    printf("p = %p\n", p);
    func(&p);
    printf("p inc: %p\n", p);
    return 0;
}
int func(int **p)
{
    (*p)++;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Almost. You are still passing a pointer by value. The only thing that changed is the type of object the pointer points to.

Answer (score 1):

You increment the pointer, not the value.

Try like this

```
(*p)++;
```

And

```
printf("p inc: %d\n", *p);
```

You need to understand pointers. A pointer is simply a variable that stores the memory address where the data actually is. You can access the data by using the dereference operator `*`, so if you want to change the data, you simply dereference the pointer, and then modify the data.

Likewise, for printing you want to see the value of the data.

In your code, you only modify the pointer. In c you always pass by value, a copy of the pointer itself is created inside the `func()` function, initially it holds the same address as your original pointer, but since it's a copy, increment it will only affect the address in the local copy.

Further more, since it's pointing to a variable on the stack. The increment operation on it will result in a pointer that you can't dereference because it would be undefined behavior.

If you want to increment the address of the pointer, you need to pass a pointer to the pointer, like this

```
void func(int **p)
{
    (*p)++;
}
```

and in main

```
func(&p);
```

note that the body of `func()` is the same, because you once again need to get access to the memory pointed to by `p` in order to modify it.

Comment: Suggest you get rid of the "virtual" and the footnote. C has *no* concept of virtual and physical memory.

Answer (score 1):

There's no passing by reference in C. When you pass a pointer to a function, you are passing a memory address by value.

When, inside the function, you do this:

```
int func(int *p)
{
    p++;
    return 0;
}
```

...you are only incrementing the memory address indicated by the parameter `p` by `sizeof *p` bytes.

In order to "simulate" passage by reference in C, you need to explicitly dereference the pointer to access the actual object. If `p` is a *properly assigned and valid* pointer, then `*p` is the object it points to. If a non-pointer expression were this:

```
a = a + 1;
```

...then with `p == &a` it would become this:

```
*p = *p + 1;
```

...or simply `(*p)++`. Notice that the parenthesis are necessary because, otherwise, C will read this as `*(p++)`. You can also get used to writing `++*p` instead.